# jQuery - Surround images not already surrounded by an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

i've encountered a problem while completing a website with huge content. We were setting a lightbox on all the images in the content. Accidently the "lightbox" class has been set on the images and no link  was created around the image.

So i figured out i could use jQuerys wrap() function to add the lightbox-image link around every image in the content area. Sadly it's also wrapping images already surrounded by an anchor (for example PDF-Links) and overwrites them.

How can i tell jQuery to only surround images in content wich are not already part of an anchor tag?

I've got the following right now :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
$('article img').each(function(){
if ($('article img').hasClass('lightbox')){
$(this).removeAttr('class');
}
$(this).wrap('<a href="'+this.src.replace("http://www.mydomain.com","")+'" class="lightbox" rel="group1"></a>');
});
$('.lightbox').lightbox();
});
</script>
```

So i am removing the lightbox class from the image and adding an anchor around every image with the same src as the image (no thumbnails).

Comment: Why not just do `.removeClass('lightbox')` to remove that one class, rather than removing the entire attribute?

Comment: I did that before, but it's leaving the class attribute empty in like <img src="somesrc.jpg" style />

Comment: Having an empty attribute doesn't seem like a big deal, personally. Removing only the class you don't want means you won't need to change the code if you start adding other classes to the `<img>` tags that you do want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/awoxiq/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('article img').each(function(){
  if( this.parentNode.tagName != 'A' ){
      $(this).removeClass('lightbox')
             .wrap('<a href="'+this.src.replace("http://www.mydomain.com","")+'" class="lightbox" rel="group1"></a>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector

```
$('article>img').each(function(){
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, while what you say is correct, there's absolutely no evidence that it's *relevant*. You don't know the DOM structure of the page, you can't know that `$('article>img')` is going to select anything. Basically what you've done is made an unfounded - and probably incorrect - guess.

Comment: True, but the selector can be tweaked to reflect the HTML structure. I believe that tweaking CSS selector is more efficient and prettier.